# How to copy one column data into another column in oracle

Tags: oracle

I want to copy one column data into another column without
   replacing the old data. For example :

Table-1

```
Column1    Column2 

SONY       Sony  Desc
Lenovo     Lenovo Desc 
Nokia      Nokia Desc
```

I would like result like

```
Column 1        column2
SONY            Sony  Desc
Sony  Desc
Lenovo          Lenovo Desc 
Lenovo Desc      
Nokia            Nokia Desc 
Nokia Desc
```

I have tried my query not match

```
Update table1 set column1 = column2
```

Comment: Yes I have tried but i didn't get it above result like , because I need to display EXTJS Tree-panel column 1 SONY as Parent Node ,Sony Desc as Child Node if any alternate way to achieve ?

Comment: "Yes" is not an answer to the question "what have you tried". Update your question to include the code that you have, that is not working. Include the (incorrect) result of that code as well. Don't put stuff like **Edit** or **Update** in your revised question when you do. This site has edit history, those who need to see differences can get the information from there.

Comment: Yes your right I have tried so many ways but still i cannot get it my  expected result ? another query I have tried but not match my requirements : Merging Columns :  select column1 || column2 from table1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `column1` has a **NOT NULL constraint**, or if it is has the **primary key constraint**, then you won't be able to insert NULL values. You need to filter out the NULL values:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (column1)
  SELECT column2 
   FROM table1 
  WHERE column2 IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks for responds me , but column1 as a nullable yes and column2 as a nullable yes .after used above query still I cannot insert my data ?**SQL Error: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("ECS_HIS"."T_KPI_AUTO_EXPORT_CONFIG"."EXPORT_CONFIG_ID")**
01400. 00000 -  "cannot insert NULL into (%s)"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to insert NULL into previously listed objects.
*Action:   These objects cannot accept NULL values.

Comment: I also refer this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20817280/ora-01400-and-ora-02296-cannot-insert-null-or-modify-added-column-properties-t?rq=1

Comment: @sameer, do you have triggers in your table that would cause this?

Comment: Sorry I don't create any trigger ? still I am not able to insert my data if any alternate way to do this ?

Comment: @sameer, describe both the tables.

Comment: I have table like that :**EXPORT_CONFIG_ID NUMBER(18,0) No  1 Default id
MS VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) Yes  2 Default 
REPORT_NAME VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) Yes  3 Default**

Comment: Above MS and Report_name as my table filed names .

Comment: Difficult to see in the comments, edit your question and add the table details.

Comment: @sameer, looks like you have a primary key / id column (`EXPORT_CONFIG_ID`) you did not mention in your question. I have edited my answer so that it will now insert a numerical value to the id column from a sequence (`SEQ_EXPORT_CONFIG_ID`). You would need to find out where your existing export config ids came from (is there already a sequence for this) or to create a new sequence for populating the ids.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add rows, you need to `INSERT` instead of `UPDATE`. This statement will add new rows that have the `column1` value copied from `column2` of another row in the table and the primary key (`export_config_id`) value taken from a sequence (`seq_export_config_id`):

```
INSERT INTO table1
(export_config_id, column1)
SELECT seq_export_config_id.NEXTVAL, column2 FROM table1;
```

Comment: I cannot able to insert null column data please let me know how can I have insert  data without allowing null values ?

Comment: @sameer, you need to filter out the NULL values, see my answer.

Comment: 'SQL Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (ECS_HIS.PK_T_KPI_AUTO_EXPORT_CONFIG) violated' because I don't have sequence column.

Comment: after created sequence column I have done . can I have inserted by sorting wise ?

Comment: @sameer, you could use e.g. `ORDER BY column2` in the `SELECT` if the sequence order needs to match the alphabetical order of `column2` values for the newly inserted rows. However, you normally worry about sorting data only when you query the table, not when you are inserting rows into the table.